# Хранимая функция PostgreSQL на С

Tags: c, postgresql

Проблема заключается в том, что сервер PostgreSQL падает при вызове следующей функции. В качестве аргумента в функцию пробовал передавать `bit()` и bit varying(). В итоге хочу написать функции, которые преобразовывают `bit(32)` в `int`  и `real`. Подскажите в каких заголовочных файлах лежит информация по `bit()` и причину по которой сервер может падать.

Код:

```
#include <postgres.h>
#include <fmgr.h>
#include <utils\varbit.h>

#ifdef PG_MODULE_MAGIC
    PG_MODULE_MAGIC;
#endif

PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(apr1);
Datum apr1(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS){
    VarBit* vb = PG_GETARG_VARBIT_P_COPY(0);
    PG_RETURN_INT32(VARBITLEN(vb));

}
```

Comment: а написать функцию — это самоцель? postgres вроде умеет и сам преобразовывать... ЗЫ: код следует добавлять прямо в вопрос...

Comment: С приведённым кодом УМВР... само собой он возвращает длину, а не значение... так что проблема где-то ещё: как собираешь/регистрируешь функцию? какой именно бектрейс при креше? ЗЫ: в Си для путей лучше использовать прямые слеши.

Comment: Посмотреть что есть из себя Datum, может это ссылочный тип, или структура, тогда конечно будет падать.

Comment: @NewView Datum это uintptr_t. Объясни пожалуйста почему падает?

Comment: @Fat-Zer на сколько я знаю Postgre не может преобразовать bit(32) в real

Comment: Так и возвращайте тот тип который требует - uintptr_t,  [почитать об этом](https://www.viva64.com/ru/t/0050/) - Это целое число без знака, равное размеру указателя.

Comment: @SergeyChernykh, зависит от того, что ты хочешь получить от такого преобразования... например всегда можно преобразовать в `integer`, а затем в `real`... а если нужно рассмотреть последовательность бит, как IEEE754, то тут да — пожалуй самым простым и быстрым будет функция на Си.